# how to link from 1jframe to another jframe

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, frame

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
//import mainFrame.java;

public class login{
 public static void main(String [] args){
 JFrame f = new JFrame();
 final JLabel label= new JLabel();
 label.setBounds(20,150,220,70);
 final JPasswordField value = new JPasswordField();
 value.setBounds(130,75,100,30);
 JLabel l1 = new JLabel("Username :");
 l1.setBounds(50,25,140,30);
 JLabel l2 = new JLabel("Password :");
 l2.setBounds(50,75,70,30);
 JButton b = new JButton("Login");
  b.setBounds(100,120, 70,30);    
        final JTextField text = new JTextField();  
        text.setBounds(130,20, 100,30);    

                b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){  
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {       

                    /* JFrame  mainFrame = new JFrame();                   
                       mainFrame.setVisible(true);
                       //mainFrame.setSize(200, 300);

                       f.setVisible(false);
                         //this.f.dispose();*/



             }); 

             f.add(value); 
             f.add(l1); 
             f.add(label);
             f.add(l2); 
             f.add(b); 
             f.add(text);            
                f.setSize(300,300);    
                f.setLayout(null);    
                f.setVisible(true);  
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 

 }
}
```

above one is my code for login panel so i can link to my mainframe panel but i am not able to link with my main frame what am i doing mistake i didn't get and i will be doing form validation later .

and here is my main frame which i want to call

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

class mainFrame{
 public static void main(String args[]){

 JFrame f = new JFrame("Main Frame");


 f.setSize(400,500); 
 f.setVisible(true);//making the frame visible 
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);   

 }
}
```

so how do i call this mainframe from login frame

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to execute your mainframe after login validation.
All you have to do is to change your JButton 'b' ActionListener in your login class to this:-

```
b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){  
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){  
mainFrame MainFrame = new mainFrame();
//MainFrame.setVisible(true);     
});
```

Comment: i tried this one already it didnt work so i post the question

Comment: Check your code again....You have created a new JFrame of name 'mainFrame' and made it visible instead of calling the mainFrame class. You just try the code I gave(try as it is, if it didnt work make the comment 'MainFrame.setVisible(true)', a part of code).